# Password check mysqli_num_rows always returns 0

Tags: php, jquery

I have written the following code to username and password against the database. Problem is that it says "Password is incorrect" even when it is. mysqli_num_rows seems to be returning 0 when it shouldn't be. Please help!

Connecting to database

```
<?php  
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "mysql";
$dbname = "Inventorydb";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, "Inventorydb");

// check the connection
if($conn === false)
{
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else 
{
    echo ("successfully connected to the database Inventorydb");
    echo "<br />";
}              
?>
```

Login php code

```
<?php 
// Parse the log in form if the user has filled it out and pressed "LogIn"
if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) 
{
    // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["username"]);

    // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["password"]);

    // Connect to the MySQL database  
    include "../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 

    // query the person
    $sql = "SELECT id 
            FROM admin 
            WHERE username='$manager' 
              AND password='$password' 
            LIMIT 1";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    // ------- MAKE SURE PERSON EXISTS IN DATABASE ---------
    // count the row nums
    $existCount = mysqli_num_rows($result); 

    echo $existCount;

    if ($existCount == 1) 
    { 
        // evaluate the count
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        { 
            $id = $row["id"];
        }

        $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
        $_SESSION["manager"] = $manager;
        $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo 'That information is incorrect, try again <a href="index.php">Click Here</a>';
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Try using the originally posted username + password, preg_replace may be messing it up. Also, before querying the database, log the manager and password to see if they match in the database

Comment: You could print the `$sql` just before you run it.  Then try it directly on the database (with phpmyadmin for example) and ensure the data matches what you are expecting.  The code is ok.  Except one detail, do you store the password directly in the database without encryption?  Look into php password functions please!

Comment: This is *not* a secure or responsible way to handle logins. You should never store passwords in plain text. Nor should you restrict passwords to such narrow character sets. Also, your regexes don't make sense (using `A-Za-z` with the `i` flag is redundant). In short: Please don’t roll your own authentication (login) system for any reason other than practice, and don’t use your own code for this in production. There are far too many ways to get it wrong and open up major security vulnerabilities. Instead, you should use an existing library or framework that has been thoroughly tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your

```
include "../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
```

has

```
$password = "mysql";
```

in it so

```
$password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["password"]);
```

gets overridden. Also don't use plain text passwords and parameterize your query.

See:

1. https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php
2. https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

To solve your issue either rename the variable in the script, or include the DB connection earlier.

Additionally

```
mysql_fetch_array
```

wont work with `mysqli` and likely will cause a fatal error for you in the future. Use `mysqli` functions everywhere.

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed the problem. Like you said it was because $password was getting overridden. Also, I will look into the password_hash() function.

Comment: Also look into prepared statements and parameterizing the query. If this resolves your issue please accept the answer.